# Express & NodeJS : Accessing response parameters from Multipart form POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, httpresponse

I have a simple form that allows the user to upload a file type image, and append the "category" type of the file to the response body, via a radio input selection.

The file processing itself is handled as expected on the backend - however, when it comes to accessing parameters in the response body, I am receiving UNDEFINED as the parameter value. Can anyone lend some pointers on what I may have overlooked ?

here is a sample of the mark-up and back end script:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="js/blueimp-gallery.min.js" async></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" async></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" async></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="main">
            <div class="navbar-wrapper" style="border: 12px solid black;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div>
                <form 
                        id              =  "uploadForm"
                        enctype         =  "multipart/form-data"
                        action          =  "/api/photo"
                        method          =  "post">

                    <input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

                    <label>travel</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="travel"      name="cat">
                    <label>food</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="food"        name="cat">
                    <label>community</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="community"   name="cat">
                </form>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>







app.post('/api/photo', function(req,res){

    console.log("request to upload image recvied.. upload in progress.");
    //console.log("res.catype() = TODO " + req.get("cat"));


    // Returning undefined*
    console.log("res.catype() = " + res.cat);

    // handle file persistence to disk.
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi part forms (forms with an attached file like an image), you need to use [Multer](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) (or some other multiform parser) on your NodeJS server instead of body-parser.  The link will give you an example of how to set this up.  Assuming your Client side HTML/JS is setup properly, you will be able to extract the image as a file and the request as body info.

The serverside NodeJS would look something like this:

```
app.post('/api/photo', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
    var files = req.files;
    if (files) {//Checks to see if any attached files
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            console.log('FILE');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(file));//contents of file
            console.log(JSON.stringify(file.filename));
        });
    }
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/resources/JSONStructures/genericResponse.json");
});
```

If you could post your Client Side JavaScript it would help a little in determining what's causing the issue.  Specifically I see a lot of AJAX being setup the short and easy way which will cause issues with multi forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should access your `cat` value from `req.body.cat`, refer http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body for more detail

Comment: Hi alpha, trying this approach leaves me with a TypeError for 'cat' as undefined. I should have mentioned I have tried this before.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you post your entire server-side code, but I don't any reference to the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware. You should use it to process any incoming "post". And you should always declare them before your routes. This way, you can access the data with `req.body`.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/photo', function(req,res){

    console.log("request to upload image recvied.. upload in progress.");
    //console.log("res.catype() = TODO " + req.get("cat"));


    // Returning undefined*
    console.log("res.catype() = " + res.cat);

    // handle file persistence to disk.
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});
```